# How often and how long will take to do Forward Splits

Tags: workout

I am beginner to this.I am gona try this.How long time(mounths) will it take to obtain this stretch movement?I mean to be in ground  ,because now,when I stretch my legs , from ground I have a long distance.I am not asking workouts,I ask how long and how much repetition needs in a day to gain this in mounths or mounths. I walk and playing football.I refer those may have an impact on this exercise.
I am 24 year old
In my 12 year old I was doing full forward splits there is a long time since then

Answer (score -1):

If you were not born flexible to begin with you are not going to get any newbie flexibility gains, flexibility training is completely the opposite of strength training.

In strength training you might get 20%-30% of your overall maximum gains in about of 1 year of decent training and then it drastically slows down until you reach a genetic limit after 20-30 years.

But when it comes to flexibility training, you will pass 1-2 years training to become flexible without seeing any result... After 2-3 years have passed you might start to see some improvement and then it will slowly get faster, and maybe after 10-15 years you will be able to do a full split.

This assuming you were not born flexible to begin with, because flexibility is 99.9% genetic.  Some people are born with strong joints, other people are born with flexible joints.

Why is it so?

Because joints need to completely change their anatomical composition for you to increase your flexibility which takes years or decades, but for strength all you need is food and heavy weights.

Also it is hard to do cardio/strength or even hypertrophy training when you are too flexible, when joints are too mobile you have greater chances to injure yourself when lifting weights.

Comment: Joints do not have anything to do with flexibility. Flexibility is a muscle function, with some people having limitation because of skeletal structure.

Comment: Is this answer right?